# TYPO3 beginner seaks template files

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

It can't be too hard to find those template files. Where are they? I am pretty sure that this actual TYPO3 installation does neither use TempVoila nor ExtBase/Fluid to handle it's template.

So I got a TypoScript Template

```
page.logo.file = 1:/xy/lablabla.png

page.theme.copyright.text = Erstellt durch <a href="http://www.xxxxx.fr">Fooobarr</a>

page.logo.height = 154
page.logo.width = 143
page.logo.alt = xxx

page.theme.news.list.maxWInText = 0
page.theme.navigationtype = top

plugin.tt_news.pid_list = 53
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = 55
plugin.tt_news.backPid = 54
```

And that's it. The template in the frontend is displayed fine. How can I find out where the hell those freaking HTML files are stored on the FTP-Server?

I faced this several times I faced a TYPO3 installation. Is there a standard path or what?

Regards, Chris

Comment: This can't be all configuration there is. Did you look up if more TypoScript is included in your main template? If you "Edit the whole template record" there should be a tab "Includes" where another template record is stated. If that isn't the case, use the Template Analyzer to see whats going on and where the page object is actually comming from.

Comment: Okay, I see. The rest of the TypoScript must have come from the bootstrap_backage extention, doen't it? I guess the bootstrap_package extention generates the "include" where the TypoScript ist stored in? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Since I've never used the bootstrap extension, I can't really tell you. But the Template Analyzer should give you a pretty good idea of that. You can basically browse the whole configuration and look up, where each setting is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have "**`bootstrap_package`**" extension installed. This is not a standard (system) extension, but you can make your setup easier with it.

The `pages.theme` settings in your TypoScript is a setting from bootstrap. See here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html

So in this case, you files are in the:

```
/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
```

And actually it uses Fluid and TypoScript to render your templates but this is a good starting point to look for your BE Layout like Default, 2 Columns 25-75 and so on.

Comment: You are right: This is based on the bootstrap_package extension. But I'm curious: When I rename the Resources-folder, nothing changes. I try flushing caches...

Comment: Okay, renaming the Resources-folder and flushing the cache fails, which is good. But again: Renaming neither theme.css nor theme.min.css has an effect. Even after flushing the cache.

Comment: those are generated from the bootstrap less files. They will be regenerated. In bootstrap_package you load the theme.less file as a resource and not the css files. A PHP Logic takes care that the less files with an extra layer of TypoScript variables generated on the rendering time. (as a css)

Comment: And if it helped you find the HTML files, could you please mark the answer as accepted to help the others too if they are facing with the same problem? :) That would be awesome! :)